# how can I make only back ground of button as transparent

Tags: asp.net, css

I am trying to create one glass button using following code in Css and asp.net

I want to make the only back ground should be transparent but text should be visible

before or after mouse over

but I am not able to make back ground of button transparent .when I give opcitt value 0

whole button including text become transparent .But I want only back ground should be transparent and text should be visible..

PLEASE HELP ME

my Css code:

```
.classnameL
 {

         text-indent:1px;
        display:inline-block;

        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:17px;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-style:normal;
         height:32px;
        line-height:50px;
        width:144px;
        padding 0px 0px 0px 0px;

        text-align:center;
        cursor: pointer;
        color:#ffffff;
        opacity:0;

   }
 .classnameL:hover 
 {
         background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom,color-stop(0.05,      #77d42a), color-stop(5, #5cb811) );
          background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #132354 60%, #c0C0C0 90% );
            filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#77d42a',endColorstr='#5cb      811');
         background-color:#5cb811;
         color:#ffffff;
         opacity:1;
  }
  .classnameL:active 
 { 
          position:relative;
          top:1px;
  }
```

My Asp.net markup code:

```
                                                     <td style="text-align: left"  >
              <asp:Button ID="btnTower" Text="Tower" runat="server"       class="classnameL"  
                       Font-Bold="False" Height="25px" Width="100%"       ForeColor="White"    ></asp:Button>
                                 </td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `background-color:transparent;` CSS property

```
.classnameL
  {
  ....
  background-color:transparent;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you wanted the text to always show and when you hover have the background go transparent. For some reason your Text tag wasn't working so I got rid of it, and I did a quick refactor of a lot of your code and some formatting

```
<td style="text-align: left">
<asp:Button ID="btnTower" runat="server" class="classnameL" Height="25px" Width="100%"/>Tower</asp:Button>
</td>

<style type="text/css">
  .classnameL {
    background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom,color-stop(0.05, #77d42a), color-stop(5, #5cb811)); 
    text-indent: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 2em;
    width: 144px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000;
  }
  .classnameL:hover {
    background: transparent;
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#77d42a',endColorstr='#5cb811 ');
  }

  .classnameL:active { 
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add below attribute in your button tag

`style="background-color: Transparent"`

Try replacing your asp code with this

```
<td style="text-align: left">
<asp:Button ID="btnTower" Text="Tower" runat="server"class="classnameL"  
  Font-Bold="False" Height="25px" Width="100%" ForeColor="White"  style="background-color: Transparent">
</asp:Button>
</td>
```